# notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't update ListView

Tags: android, listview, datasource, listviewitem, listadapter

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            deserializeQuotes();
            quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

My array clearly has been updated, and I can see the change when my app starts, but why doesn't it update in this method? The code enters this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.quotesAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(this, R.layout.mainrow, quotes);      
            quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(quotesAdapter);
```

Works, but why do I have to create a new adapter? Why can't I use my existing one?

Comment: We need more code. You're probably overwriting the reference to quotes somewhere